# How can I upgrade to Firefox 34.0.5 on Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, firefox, repository

I have Firefox 34.0 installed on a system running Ubuntu 14.04 (Trusty).  Many websites want to inform me that my browser is outdated, as apparently 34.0.5 has some significant security updates.  Other major websites inform me that 34.0.5 should be available in the Ubuntu repositories as of about 4-Dec, but as of this date (21-Dec) even packages.ubuntu.com shows only 34.0, not 34.0.5.

I'm reluctant to download an offline installer for 34.0.5 because I don't want to screw up my system by having two separate versions installed in two separate directories.

I guess my question is: is there any good reason why 34.0.5 wouldn't be available from the standard Ubuntu repositories despite having been out for several weeks now?

Comment: Have you run `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade firefox` to check?

Comment: Yyou can check whether your version is the latest or not by seeing if it says *'Congrats! You’re using the latest version of Firefox. '* here: https://www.mozilla.org/en-GB/firefox/new/

Comment: @Wilf Running the latest build from all updates/security updates repositories on Trusty satisfies that test page.  I'm curious now as to what is so special about 34.0.5 and what is so wrong with 34.0 as specifics are ***not*** given above relative to the flaws.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, Firefox 34.0.5 is the version that switched US users from Google to Yahoo search. ([source here](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=23&t=2891765))

Firefox in Ubuntu and derivatives is unaffected, but if you wish to switch the default search engine to something else, just change it in the search bar.

PS: I can also confirm that Firefox 34 is not "upgradeable" to 34.0.5 on Windows, ...probably because I am not in the US.

Answer (score -1):

The reason why Firefox 34.0.5 isn't on Trusty's repository is because Ubuntu versions are released in cycles and they release each Ubuntu version with packages that deem to be most stable to provide Long Time Support. So if I want to downgrade to Ubuntu 12.04, it will have all the older versions of packages that were provided with Ubuntu 12.04 at release.

If you wish to upgrade your firefox, you might have some issues with it due to it not being optimized for Ubuntu + Unity. For instance your toolmenu for Firefox will be hidden and not combine with the titlebar. Also adding non-official repositories can be dangerous since anything could be in there. So it would be your duty to see if the version of Firefox you're adding is secure as well being compatible with your desktop environment (Unity).

Comment: This completely ignores the security updates and stable release updates that are made for packages like Firefox.  While technically accurate it doesn't reflect the reality of a running system that is ever updated.

Answer (score -2):

Currently, the best method seems to be downloading manually. On a 64-bit system:

```
wget ftp.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/firefox/releases/34.0.5/linux-x86_64/en-US/firefox-34.0.5.tar.bz2
tar -xjvf firefox-34.0.5.tar.bz2
sudo mv firefox /opt/firefox34.0.5
sudo ln -sf /opt/firefox34.0.5/firefox /usr/bin/firefox
```

This will only overwrite the symbolic link in `/usr/bin`, so there should be no conflict between the two installations. You can restore the link and use the old version with the following command:

```
sudo ln -sf /usr/lib/firefox/firefox /usr/bin/firefox
```

Or just run 34.0.5 without linking:

```
/opt/firefox34.0.5/firefox
```

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the question.

Comment: Can you please tell me how my answer "doesn't actually answer" the question "How can I upgrade to Firefox 34.0.5 on Ubuntu 14.04?"

Comment: You provide a splendid explanation of how to download from Mozilla the binary and install it.  You answered the headline only.  The body of the question asks why 34.0.5 is not in trusty's repositories.  The two are very different things.